# Jquery attributeContainsWord selector keeps adding string to my variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to make a dropdown menu, while changing list selection it will change css property display of some  to none to hide. But it keeps adding new string to my variable.

```js
$("#select").change(function () {
  
    $(points).val('');
    var points = $("#select :selected" ).text();
   
    $('span[alt~="'+points+'"]').css('display', 'block');
  
    });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>attributeContains demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <select name="" id="select">
    <option value="">Select an brand</option>
    <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
    <option value="MAN">MAN</option>
    <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
  </select>
 
  <span alt="MAN" style="display:none">Number 1</span>
  <span alt="BMW" style="display:none">Number 2</span>
  <span alt="MAN" style="display:none">Number 3</span>
  <span alt="Volvo" style="display:none">Number 4</span>
  <span alt="MAN" style="display:none">Number 5</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is `$(points).val('');` supposed to work when `points` is set _after_ that line?

Comment: Why `.text()` and not `.val()` in `$("#select :selected" ).text();`?

Comment: And why `.val('')`?

Comment: You're not doing anything to set `display: none` on the spans you've previously set `display: block` on, so they'll remain visible. I strongly recommend using classes, not `.css`, not least because you can then do `$(".show").removeClass("show");` to hide the previous ones before doing (say) `$('span[alt~="'+points+'"]').addClass("show");` Also, you have multiple spans with `alt="MAN"`, which confuses matters a bit. :-)

Comment: is there any way to set all other <span> to display: none?

Comment: `$("span")` will select *all* spans (across your whole page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things

1. A span that is display:block can just as well be a div
2. spans do not have alt. That is an image attribute. I changed to data attributes
3. You need the value and not the text
4. hide before you show - no need for css

```js
$("#select").on("change", function() {
  const val = $(this).val();
  $('div[data-val]').hide(); // hide them first 
  if (val === "") return; // nothing to show
  $(`div[data-val=${val}]`).show()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="select">
  <option value="">Select an brand</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="MAN">MAN</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<div data-val="MAN" style="display:none">Number 1</div>
<div data-val="BMW" style="display:none">Number 2</div>
<div data-val="MAN" style="display:none">Number 3</div>
<div data-val="Volvo" style="display:none">Number 4</div>
<div data-val="MAN" style="display:none">Number 5</div>
```

Using class and toggle in vanilla JS

```js
const list = [...document.querySelectorAll(`div[data-val]`)];
document.getElementById("select").addEventListener("change", function() {
  const val = this.value;
  list.forEach(div => div.classList.toggle("hide",val !== div.dataset.val))
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none }
```

```html
<select name="" id="select">
  <option value="">Select an brand</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="MAN">MAN</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<div data-val="MAN" class="hide">Number 1</div>
<div data-val="BMW" class="hide">Number 2</div>
<div data-val="MAN" class="hide">Number 3</div>
<div data-val="Volvo" class="hide">Number 4</div>
<div data-val="MAN" class="hide">Number 5</div>
```

Comment: Thnaks bro! That works like nothing else.

Comment: I missed to leave if val is empty in version 1